# HTML tag "readonly" changes depending on computer?

Tags: html

How is it possible that the homepage www.ebookers.com has "readonly" html tags, depending on what computer I open it from? Concretely:

- if I open the page from my desktop in chrome, I am able to type in dates with my keyboard
- if i open the page from my laptop, same Win10, same chrome, same wifi, the date fields are "readonly" and I can only use the datepicker to input dates.

If I use incognito mode or Firefox, it is consistent, it seems just to depend on the machine I sit at whether a tag is there on a homepage. Granted I know very little about web development, but this is completely bamboozling to me, it makes no sense.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Especially if there is a way to disable/circumvent that readonly mode, as this would facilitate my selenium scripting considerably. Thanks!

Comment: `If I use incognito mode or Firefox, it is consistent,` in what way? consistently failing? consistently working?

Comment: consistently just depending on the computer, so in Firefox i get the same situation where the readonly tag is just on my laptop, while i can easily type into the input with my keyboard on if i use my desktop pc.

Comment: how are you assigning the readonly attribute? showing your html might go a long way :)

Comment: The form is generated with javascript, you can see this by disabling javascript and the form is not generated at all. Seems that the javascript simply has a condition that checks the width of the screen and if it's small enough it adds the readonly-attribute

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much Esko, I would have never figured this out without your input!

Comment: and thank you ThisGuy, i meant it was about a homepage (see above) that already exists, i have no html code myself. i was just wondering why the page was sometimes readonly and sometimes not and it seemed to depend on the computer you accessed it from. but thank you!